# How to use $subtract with array of document in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

We have two collections in which have **users** and **organizations**.

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {$match: {"organization.metaInfo":{"$ne": "disabled"}}},
   {"$unwind":"$organization"},
   {"$group":{"_id":"$organization.organizationId", "count":{"$sum":1}}},
   {$lookup: {from: "organisations",
              localField: "_id",
             foreignField: "_id", as: "orgDta"}},
   {"$project":{"_id":1, "count":1, 
              "orgDta.organizationLicence.userCount":1     
   }}

])
```

When this query is performed return a result like which is good to me.

```
{
  "_id" : "768d3090-d4f5-11e7-a503-9b68b90cdb4e",
  "count" : 5.0,
  "orgDta" : [{ 
           "organizationLicence" : {
              "userCount" : 50
          }
    }]
},
{
  "_id" : "d9933740-c29c-11e7-9481-b52c5f3e2e70",
  "count" : 1.0,
  "orgDta" : [{
          "organizationLicence" : {
            "userCount" : 1
        }
    }] 
 },
 {
   "_id" : "5386ebc0-c29b-11e7-9481-b52c5f3e2e70",
    "count" : 1.0,
    "orgDta" : [{
           "organizationLicence" : {
             "userCount" : 1
         }
    }]
 }
```

**Now, I want to perform a subtract operation in between count and userCount.But I don't know that how to use here.**

I was trying together with **$project**

> {"$project":{"_id":1, "count":1, "orgDta.dObjects":1, "orgDta.organizationLicence.userCount":1, 
>    "remainingUser": { $subtract: [ "$orgDta.organizationLicence.userCount", "$count"]}

But Mongo returns error

> {
>       "message" : "cant $subtract adouble from a array",
>       "stack" : "MongoError: cant $subtract adouble from a array" }

Comment: Why do you unwind and group the `organization` ? Can you explain your requirement ? Btw, you can use `$arrayElemAt` to project first element when userCount array only has 1 element. Try `"remainingUser": { $subtract: [ {$arrayElemAt:["$orgDta.organizationLicence.userCount",0]}, "$count"]}`]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$group` instead wih `$unwind` (before) like this,

Aggregate pipeline

```
db.users.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: '$orgDta'
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                remainingUser: {
                    $push: {
                        $subtract: ['$orgDta.organizationLicence.userCount', '$count']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

What we are doing here is unwind the target array, subtract all the elements (in your case, the element child's element value) and then group the array back with result (of substraction) value.

**Add other items you might want in your final result document, above is just a sample MongoDB aggregate query.**

Comment: @Nites Singh.Thanks!